# How to insert emoticons in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, emoticons

I know it's a long shot, but is there some package or means to insert emoticons into a LaTeX document?

Comment: See also this question: [How to use Noto Color Emoji with lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497403/how-to-use-noto-color-emoji-with-lualatex/591811)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I know at least two partial ways:

First:

```
$\ddot\smile$
```

Second:

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\smiley
\frownie
```

Or you can use images (as mentioned in other replies).

Comment: Seems like the package uses raster font :(

Answer (score 17):

What's against a simple {\tt :-)}?

Comment: We use LaTeX so we can get nice graphical forms instead of plain text renditions. ​☺

Comment: Indeed, but true emoticons – as opposed to emoji or other graphical icons – intrinsically consist of “plain text” characters.

Answer (score 12):

If you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola}
\begin{document}

 
\end{document}
```

should produce black-and-white emoji letters in Symbola font,
which is available from http://users.teilar.gr/%7Eg1951d/
or standard package repositories in some Linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu).
The MS Windows emoji font can also be used by `\fontspec{Segoe UI Emoji}[RawFeature={ccmp,dist}]`
in place of `\fontspec{Symbola}`.

Unfortunately the color (emoji) fonts are not supported by the standard
lualatex or xelatex. `harflatex` and `luahblatex` can typeset color emojis using

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{harfload}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\fontspec{Noto Color Emoji}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
☃⛄‍‍‍\quad ‍❤️‍‍
\end{document}
```

`harflatex` and `luahblatex` can be installed from TeXLive Contrib at
https://contrib.texlive.info/ as of July 2019.

The above is learnt from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497403/how-to-use-noto-color-emoji-with-lualatex/500180
with a bit of my own investigation.

Answer (score 5):

Unicode's "miscellaneous symbols" include 3 simple emoticons: `0x2639`-`0x263B`. You can possibly use `0x2686`-`0x2689` as well.

For more variation you are going to need to use images and include them somehow.

I am curious as to the circumstances which lead to this question :)

Comment: I prepare the assignment handout for my students in LaTeX (exported to PDF). I would love to include a smiley in there for the students :-)

Comment: Ah, I guess that is justified - I would like to see smilies in my assignments. Though not if you only put them in hard questions, and following by "this should be easy" :P

Comment: Good idea, but to apply this you need to know how to enter Unicode characters.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219853/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex

Answer (score 4):

By now there also is the `tikzsymbols` package which has nice emoticons.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use bclogo package. It contains two smileys (happy & sad), plus many other small "logos" like flags and others.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{emoji}

\begin{document}

These are colour emojis using the \texttt{emoji} package and LuaLaTeX:
\emoji{leaves}
\emoji{rose}

You can use emoji-modifiers:
\emoji{woman-health-worker-medium-skin-tone}
\emoji{family-man-woman-girl-boy}
\emoji{flag-malaysia}
\emoji{flag-united-kingdom}

\end{document}
```

Also, set the compiler to **LuaLaTeX** from Menu --> Settings
[image]

[Reference](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Inserting_emojis_in_LaTeX_documents_on_Overleaf)

Answer (score -1):

\binom{.,.}{\frown} seems cute - adjust eye-spacing to taste - although it takes up a fair amount of space and is of course only an opinion.